# A function that is meant to take 2 arguments but doesnt

Tags: python

Hey all I've got a very simple and probably stupid question to ask, i'm trying to write a function that will take in two arguments a potential key and the dictionary name and if the key isn't in the dictionary it should return something along the lines of "x" is an invalid key. This is what i have so far:

```
test_dictionary = {1: 'a', 2: 'b', 3: 'c', 4: 'd'}

def show_value():
    i = ()
    if i in test_dictionary:
        pass
else:
    print((i)('is not a valid key'))

show_value(1, test_dictionary)
```

Now when i run this code it says show_value takes 0 positional arguments but two were given but when i try to put in 2 arguments it says 'tuple' object is not callable. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Your function definition does not match with your function call.

Comment: I think that's the point of the question.

Comment: Your `show_value()` does not have any arguments defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
test_dictionary = {1: 'a', 2: 'b', 3: 'c', 4: 'd'}

def show_value(i, test_dictionary):
    if i in test_dictionary:
        pass
    else:
        print(i, 'is not a valid key')

show_value(1, test_dictionary)  # OK
show_value(5, test_dictionary)  # 5 is not a valid key
```

Comment: When you have no work to be done on `if` check, why use `pass`? Reverse your `if` check.

Comment: Oh man, I can prune this code into one line `show_value = lambda x, d: d.get(x, str(x) + ' is not a valid key')`. I just give a minimal diff to show how this function works. @Austin

Comment: i'm sorry i'm still very new to python and your comment just blew my mind up hopefully i get as good as that in the future.

Comment: @Philipclarkson take it easy, you should learn python in this hard way then you can optimaize them when you go further.

Answer (score 1):

**Problems**:

- Function definition does not match with function call. If you pass two parameters, there should be two at the receiving end also.
- `i = ()` creates a tuple (does not need and replaces `i` value if you had passed it). Using `(i)(..)`, you are trying to call a tuple object, which is not possible.

**Working code**:

```
test_dictionary = {1: 'a', 2: 'b', 3: 'c', 4: 'd'}

def show_value(i, dictionary):
    if i in test_dictionary:
        print(f'{i} found')
    else:
        print(f'{i} not found')

show_value(6, test_dictionary)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the function parameters so it can accept two values.

```
def show_value(i, dict):
```

Also, your else statement is not properly aligned with an if statement above. Good luck!

Comment: no problem, accept my answer if it's the best! Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

[docs.python.org](https://docs.python.org) is a good place to go for questions like this. In your specific case I think [this](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions) is the page you want.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions) that teaches about writing functions.